# The coevaluation map for a projective module and its dual

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, monoidal-categories, projective-modules

$\DeclareMathOperator\coev{coev}$Let $R$ be a noncommutative ring and let $P$ be a bimodule over $R$, that is finitely generated and projective as a left module. It is "well-known" that any such $P$ admits a left dual ${}^{\vee}P$ in the monoidal category of $R$-bimodules. The evaluation map
$$
\operatorname{ev}:{}^{\vee}P  \otimes P \to R
$$
is clearly an $R$-bimodule map. The dual coevaluation map $\coev$ is given by
$$
\coev: R \to P \otimes_R {}^{\vee}P, ~~ r \mapsto r \sum_{i=1}^n e_i \otimes e^i,
$$
where $e_i$ and $e^i$ are dual bases for $P$ and ${}^{\vee}P$. If this is a bimodule map, then the element $\coev(1)$ would have to satisfy
\begin{equation}
\label{1}\tag{1}
r\coev(1) = \coev(1)r, ~~ \textrm{ for all } r \in R.
\end{equation}
However, I cannot see that \eqref{1} is true. Also I can't see why the element $\coev(1)$ is independent of the choice of dual basis.

Comment: I don't think you want to write $r\text{coev}(1)=r\text{coev}(1)$, because this is an identity... Also, I believe $\text{coev}$ is determined by its value on $1$, by the property that it is a $R$-bimodule homomorphism, so $1\mapsto \sum e_i\otimes e^i$ extends linearly in a unique way. And once a basis of $P$ has been fixed I believe the zig-zag identities fix the value of coev(1) uniquely (I'm thinking as if $P$ was a vector space).

Comment: @Fosco: I have corrected the typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Incidentally, I think a left dual goes on the left side of the tensor in the evaluation map.

Comment: @EH: Yes of course, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: How does your coevaluation map use its argument?  Your description of the image of $r$ does not seem to mention $r$.  (Also, why does a not-necessarily-free module have a basis?)

Comment: @LSpice: the typo has been corrected